# Slow image load/Pull images from storage - firebase - react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am pulling data from my firestore DB, one of the fields on each DB item is `image`, the value of each being a URL to an image with my firebase storage.

What I'd like to do is pull the image directly from storage as part of the loop that pulls from firestore.

I am trying to do this as when this loop renders the items, the images are taking a few seconds to appear on the screen.

Please advise if there is an alternative to solve this issue?

**FirebaseData.js**

```
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
const data = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const { title, image, url, description } = doc.data();
    data.push({
      key: doc.id,
      doc, // DocumentSnapshot
      title,
      image,
      description,
      url
    });
});
this.setState({
  data,
  loading: false
});
}

render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Spinner />; //RETURN A LOADING ICON
    }
return (
  <List containerStyle={styles.listStyle}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <ChildList {...item} />}
    />
  </List>
      );
    }
  }
```

**ChildList.js**

```
export default class ChildListRow2 extends React.PureComponent {

render() {
  return (
      <ListItem
        title={
          <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: this.props.image }} style={styles.imageStyle} />
          <Text style={styles.titleTextStyle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        subtitle={
          <View>
          <Text style={styles.subTitleTextStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        hideChevron
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.props.url)}
        containerStyle={styles.listItemStyle}
      />
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: So you want to get firestorage image in the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`onLoadEnd`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onloadend) and [`onLoadStart`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onloadstart) properties of `Image` component to show and hide the rest of the data. You can show a loading spinner till the file loads and then show the complete component when it finishes.

**Example**

```
export default class ChildListRow2 extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  imageLoaded = () => {
    this.setState({ loaded: true })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={
          <View>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: this.props.image }}
              style={styles.imageStyle} 
              onLoadEnd={this.imageLoaded}
            />
            <Text style={styles.titleTextStyle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        subtitle={
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.subTitleTextStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        hideChevron={this.state.loaded}
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.props.url)}
        containerStyle={styles.listItemStyle}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this if I am rendering the image in a separate list component file?

Comment: Without knowing how you use this data I can't suggest anything relevant. If you edit you question with some code showing how you render your component I'll try to suggest something

Comment: I've updated to show how I'm using the data in another component. As you can see I am returning a spinner until the data is loaded, but then the image takes a while to render - forcing it to look unprofessional.

Comment: @garethiv added a small example to show what sort of thing you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @garethiv glad that I could help